# Adding up number of items in an array

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I'm trying to add up all the items in my array. I've tried adapting other code to fit this but  so far I havent had much luck. I am extremely new to this.

```
var coinArray = new Array("penny", "penny", "penny", "penny", "nickle", "nickle", "nickle",          "dime", "dime", "quarter", "quarter", "half dollar");
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean with "adding up"?

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.reduce` along with key value pairs is a clean approach.

```
var coins = {
    penny: 1,
    nickle: 5,
    dime: 10,
    quarter: 25,
    "half dollar": 50
};

var result = coinArray.reduce(function(p, v) {
    return p + coins[v];
}, 0);

alert(result); // 139
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/r2G2L/

Answer (score 1):

```
total = 0;
for(i=0; i<coinArray.length; i++){
switch(coinArray[i]){
    case 'penny':
      total+1;
      break;
    case 'nickle':
      total+5;
      break;
    case 'quarter':
      total+25;
      break;
    }
    /* OTHER CASES... */
}
```

I would just like to add on a personal note that this seems a lot from a Comp-Sci class assignment :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean count how much money you have in that array, you need to assign values, I prefer using an object. Note that it should be **nickel** but I left it unchanged.

```
var amount = { "penny": 1, "nickle": 5, "dime": 10, "quarter": 25, "half dollar": 50  };
```

Then loop through the array summing up to a `total` variable

```
var total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < coinArray.length; i++) {
  // Check if coin actually exists in our values object
  if(amount.hasOwnProperty(coinArray[i].toLowerCase())) {
    total += amount[coinArray[i].toLowerCase()];
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NCch8/2/

Comment: You should force the coin name to be lowercase like the enumerator object keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
var coins = { 'penny': .01, 'nickle': .05, 'dime': .10, 'quarter': .25, 'half dollar': .50};

var coinArray = new Array("penny", "penny", "penny", "penny", "nickle", "nickle", "nickle",          "dime", "dime", "quarter", "quarter", "half dollar");

var total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < coinrArray.length; i++)
    total += coins[coinrArray[i]];
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RqaZD/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery..

```
var coinArray = new Array("penny", "penny", "penny", "penny", "nickle", "nickle", "nickle", "dime", "dime", "quarter", "quarter", "half dollar");

var total = {};

$.each(coinArray, function(item) {

    var coin = coinArray[item];

    if (!total[coin]) total[coin] = 0;

    total[coin] += 1;


});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add elements to an array using the push method

```
    var coinArray = new Array("penny", "penny", "penny", "penny", "nickle", "nickle", "nickle", "dime", "dime", "quarter", "quarter", "half dollar");
coinArray.push("cent");
```

Comment: you can push multiple items coinArray.push("cent","dollar");